How to identify the cases where the start-to-end date range intersects with a "target" date range
Picture this dataset.
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:10,
  start_date_smoking = c("28/06/2011", "27/07/2012", "09/04/2003", "01/07/2013", "28/06/2011",
                         "01/09/2013", "01/09/2013", "30/08/2014", "01/09/2013", "01/09/2013"),
  end_date_smoking = c("01/01/2017", "01/01/2017", "01/01/2017", "01/01/2017", "01/09/2013",
                       "01/09/2013", "02/09/2013", "01/01/2017", "31/08/2014", "31/08/2014")
)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    start_date_smoking =dmy(start_date_smoking),
    end_date_smoking =  dmy(end_date_smoking),
    days = time_length(difftime(end_date_smoking, start_date_smoking),"days"))
  )

How can I capture smokers/cases (IDs) who were smoking between 01-09-2013 and 31-08-2014 AND smoked for at least 180 days. I tried filter() but I can't get it to work. For example, I want to capture someone who started before 01-09-2013 (e.g., ID 1) since they were smoking between those two dates. However, I don't want to capture someone who starts smoking 30-08-2014 (e.g., ID 8) even if they smoke for several years since that won't be smoking for 180 days within the 01-09-2013 and 31-08-2014 timeframe.
Ultimately, I want it to return a df filtered to IDs 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, and 10.
I tried doing but it didn't filter to the rows I was expecting
start_range <- dmy("01/09/2013")
end_range <- dmy("31/08/2014")

df %>%
  filter(days >= 180 &
         (start_date_smoking >= start_range & start_date_smoking <= end_range) |
           (end_date_smoking >= start_range & end_date_smoking <= end_range) |
           (start_date_smoking <= start_range & end_date_smoking >= end_range))

EDIT 1: As far as I am aware, this hasn't been answered previously in other posts (e.g., here or here)
The problem with just doing the last line (i.e., filter(start_date_smoking <= start_range & end_date_smoking >= end_range) is that the code isn't discerning with the cases it's filtering. For example, if someone's start date is 1985-01-01 and end_date is 2014-05-15. Technically, they would have been smoking for 180 days between "2013-09-01" and their end_date 2014-05-15 (i.e. 255 days) But equally, I don't want them if their start date is 1986-12-01 and end_date is 2014-02-25 since they were only smoking for 177 days between "2013-09-01" and their end_date 2014-02-25.
EDIT 2: Thank you so much Jake and Ben. They both worked though I have a large dataset (over 15 million rows), so Ben's solution was quicker. There was some minor discrepancies but they just depend on if the 'enddate' is included in the count.

Try filter(df, pmin(end_date_smoking, end_range) - pmax(start_date_smoking, start_range) > 180)

You thank people by clicking the green checkmark at the upper-left of their answer, not by changing your question.

Editing in response to the clarification provided in comments...
We need to identify the cases where the start-to-end date range intersects with the "target" date range for at least 180 days.
target.date.range <- seq(as.Date("2013-09-01"), as.Date("2014-08-31"), by = "days")

for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  seq.days <- seq(df$start_date_smoking[i], df$end_date_smoking[i], by = "days")
  
  df$days.in.range[i] <- length(intersect(seq.days, target.date.range)) 
}

df %>% filter(days.in.range >= 180)

This returns:
 ID start_date_smoking end_date_smoking  days days.in.range
1  1         2011-06-28       2017-01-01  2014           365
2  2         2012-07-27       2017-01-01  1619           365
3  3         2003-04-09       2017-01-01  5016           365
4  4         2013-07-01       2017-01-01  1280           365
5  9         2013-09-01       2014-08-31   364           365
6 10         2013-09-01       2014-08-31   364           365


wait so why doesn't this work if someone's start date is 1985-01-01 and end_date is 2014-05-15. Technically, they would have been smoking for 180 days between "2013-09-01" and their end_date 2014-05-15 (i.e. 255 days)
But equally, I don't want them if their start date is 1986-12-01 and end_date is 2014-02-25 since they were only smoking for 177 days between "2013-09-01" and their end_date 2014-02-25.

Ok, your question was more complicated than it seemed! If I'm understanding correctly, we need to identify the cases where the start-to-end date range intersects with the "target" date range for at least 180 days.
This will do the trick:
`target.date.range <- seq(as.Date("2013-09-01"), as.Date("2014-08-31"), by = "days")
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
seq.days <- seq(df$start_date_smoking[i], df$end_date_smoking[i], by = "days")
df$days.in.range[i] <- length(intersect(seq.days, target.date.range))
} `
Then we can filter based on days.in.range >= 180.
